# Data on minimum wage by country?

Tags: data-request

Where can I get a dataset (yearly, if possible) containing minimum wage (US$ or other) by country?

Answer (score 1):

First, look into [List of minimum wages by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minimum_wages_by_country) in Wikipedia.
(Unfortunately, it seems that Wikidata doesn't have the "minimum wage" property.)

I have also found the following historical data:

- [OECD countries](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=RMW)
- [EU countries](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=earn_mw_cur&lang=en)
- [UN (ILO) countries](http://www.ilo.org/travail/areasofwork/wages-and-income/WCMS_142568/lang--en/index.htm)